# yo meanjs not recognizing generated project

Tags: yeoman, meanjs, yeoman-generator

I've created a new MeanJS project using Yeoman. It installs just fine. When I want to add a new module using `yo meanjs:angular-module mymodule`, it tries to create a new project `("Which mean.js version would you like to generate")` instead of just adding the new module.

Where should I look for errors?

I'm using `node v0.12.7` and `npm v2.11.3`.

Comment: https://github.com/meanjs/generator-meanjs/issues

Comment: They have removed the module generators for now.

Comment: How have you tried adding the module to the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I know this could be confusing, at least when you starting with Meanjs. You probably used a version greater than 0.3.0 (stable) and sub-generators like *yo meanjs:angular-module*  are only available (by that time of writing this) with version 0.3.0 (stable). Look at the red message top at this page: http://meanjs.org/generator.html What's confusing here is that they recommended on their page to install the application using the yeoman but after you did that you expect to be able to use sub-generators... If you want use subs, please use 0.3.0. and I suggest you to use supported Node.js and npm versions (http://meanjs.org/docs/0.3.x/#troubleshooting):

MongoDB
    MongoDB version 2.4.x is supported.
Node.js
    Node version 0.10.x is supported.
npm
    npm version 1.3.x is supported.